# VLC not applying video color adjustments

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, h.265

The changes in ADJUSTMENT AND EFFECTS doesn't effect the video played by VLC when I play 10bit HEVC video. I am running VLC 2.2.4 on Windows 10 professional.

My PC specs:

- Intel i7 2640QM
- 8 GM RAM
- Samsung 850EVO
- AMD Radeon graphics card

How can I force VLC to apply the video color settings?